# Redirect all requests with specific extension to one controller. Not working on iis7 after deploying

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-routing, http-status-code-404

This is my requirement. I want to redirect all incoming requests with .atp extension to a controller called "OrderStatus" for which I have defined below route in RouteConfig.cs

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Allatps",
            "{filename}.atp",
             new { controller = "OrderStatus", action = "Index", filename = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Now, the issue is, this route works perfectly when I run the application in local environment, but when I deploy it to server (with IIS7), it gives me 404 not found error.

Can anybody please tell me what I am missing here?

PS: I have also tried deploying the same application in local IIS with same results, not succeeding. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Suhani.

Comment: I **suppose** to redirect extension isn't just routing (when done with IIS) but rewriting (should be done in web.config).

Comment: Thank you @Adriano for your quick response.. Can you please give me any hint on how to handle this in web.config?

Comment: I would start from [this article](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/iis-url-rewriting-and-aspnet-routing) but sadly I never did it so I can't provide more hints.

Comment: Thank you for this article.. Looks like it will help. Will try the directions and will let you know the outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally adding following handlers in web.config worked for me :) Thank you Adriano for your help..

```
<add name="ATPHandler" path="*.atp" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
<add name="ATPHandler_64bit" path="*.atp" verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
```